# UIView stuck behind UITableview header

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiview

In my app I have a `UITableViewCell` with a `UITextField` in it. When the user starts typing in this textfield, an autocomplete view appears.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (self.suggestions != nil) {
        self.autocomplete = [[AutoComplete alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 53, self.frame.size.width-20, 200)];
        self.autocomplete.delegate = self;
        self.autocomplete.suggestions = self.suggestions;

        [self addSubview:self.autocomplete];
        [self bringSubviewToFront:self.autocomplete];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

This is nothing more than a `UIView` with a `UITableView` inside it. However, what happens is that this view is hidden behind the section header and the next cell. [image]

So while it appears to be inserted above the cell, it registers the tapp below it. When you click in the autocomplete it registers the click in the next cell. How can I fix this?

Comment: Why don't you make your cell bigger on tap to accommodate the inserted subview?

Comment: @user4992124 did you end up resolving this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is you are adding it to the view and not the tableview which resides in the UIView as well as having a section header that will probably block it out as well. I see your `y` position is only 53, so your header is likely blocking it out.

I am not 100% sure where you want your result to be viewed and used, that's not clear in your question. If you want your view to be above everything else you could:

1. "I have a UITableViewCell with a UITextField in it. When the user starts typing in this textfield, an autocomplete view appears." - add the result view to your cell, not the main view; `[cell.contentView addSubview...`
2. Shift your tableview down by changing it's `y` position to `self.autocomplete.view.frame.size.height`. Add a nice little animation to it as it changes position too, always something that bit extra.
3. Consider adding it as a subview to your TableView and bringing to front, should work.

([little bit extra on the cell.contentView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewcell#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/contentView))

Comment: Shouldn't you use `[cell.contentView addSubview...` ?